# Keycodes in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

What are the keycodes for numbers in tkinter? I want to bind a widget to a number.
I am using Python 3 and Windows 10.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to bind to the number 1, just use `<Key-1>`.

```
the_widget.bind('<Key-1>', some_function)
```